# Can Connectify Dispatch be used for video streaming?

Tags: video-streaming, sockets, connectify

Here is my situation. We are specialized in video producing local sports for web-streaming. In  most cases clients provide us with poor bandwidth, which is absolutely critical for us.

There is a product called [Connectify Dispatch](http://www.connectify.me/dispatch). It combines multiple Internet connections and creates a huge pipe. It seems like I found the right piece of software, but here is the problem:

> Streaming video applications typically use a single socket. In this case, Dispatch will usually make a decision to put that socket onto the fastest Internet connection, and then let all your other traffic go over the other Internet connections.

Our hardware encodes video and use RTMP-protocol to send a stream to CDN.

I need some clear explanations what socket is and will Dispatch help me to send video stream to CDN via consolidated Internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

Connectify support service responded:

> To explain how Dispatch works, whenever an application opens a socket, it decides which connection to use to send the data for that socket. Most traditional file transfer tools or streaming services only use one socket at a time, so Dispatch cannot accelerate that individual connection. Dispatch splits sockets among multiple Internet connections, so a single FTP transfer can only be put on one connection. You can however, select certain applications to use specific adapters in Dispatch Settings under the Application Tab. So if you were to start multiple FTP transfers or streaming services (assuming the program supports making multiple sockets), then you should see the speed of both interfaces.